# CUPS + AirPrint on Raspberry Pi [Solved]

Tags: command-line, printing

Im trying to install `cups`, `cups-pdf`, `avahi-discover`, and `python-cups`

But when I try to open port 631 using the following command:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp –dport 631 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp –dport 631 -j ACCEPT
```

I get the following message:

```
Bad argument `-dport'
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

Any ideas how to fix it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the input your provided, it looks like you somehow converted the expected double dash ("--") before "dport" into an endash ("–"), possibly by typing the commands in Microsoft Word or some other "helpful" editor. Or, maybe you cut and pasted it from somewhere that made the two dashes into an endash.

Since the endash doesn't make sense, you have an error. Replace the endash with two dashes.

Comment: Exactly, it worked, really appreciate it. Thanks a lot.